# No se devuelven valores de archivo json en php

Tags: php, json

Tengo la siguiente función, la cual me devuelve los valores que contiene el archivo conf.json, el cual ya verifiqué que existe, que tiene valores dentro, y que la ruta es correcta.

```
public function getJson(){
    $get = file_get_contents('conf.json');
    return json_decode($get, true);
}
```

Pero al usarla de esta manera no me devuelve nada:

$s = getJson();
echo $s['domain'];

No sale error, pero tampoco devuelve nada, y ya verifiqué que tenga los valores correctos, este es el archivo json:

{
    'domain': 'domain',
    'user': 'user'
}

Ya verifique que estuviera todo en el lugar correcto y que esté bien definido, pero sigue sin sacarme nada al llamar la función, y al llamar a "domain"

Comment: Si imprimes solo tu variable $s te muestra algo? Puedes probar tambien con print_r($s)

Comment: Al usar print_r devuelve un 1, y al imprimir &get me devuelve el archivo json sin descodificar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El JSON debe estar formado de esta forma:

```
{"key":"value","key1":"value1",..}
```

con comillas dobles, no simples.

Comment: En la documentación de [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/es/function.json-decode.php) aparece como "Errores comunes al usar json_decode()" (Ejemplo #3).

Comment: Eran las comillas, gracias.